# Conditional Format based on a specific number within a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am hoping someone can assist me with a conditional format formula which would indicate which number is in the formula.  As a simple example, I have two different formulas below:

=1+10 and =3+10

I would like a conditional format formula which would make the cell a specific color (I know how to do the formatting part) based on if the formula contains =1 (green fill) or =3 (orange fill).  I realize I may need to create two separate conditional formatting rules, but I can't seem to figure out the formula to give me the results i'm looking for.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick guide to what I think you want.

**Step 1 - The missing function**
First, we need to check a cell for the formula, and not the value.
For newer versions of excel, there's the `FORMULATEXT()` function that does just this. However, for us using older versions of Excel, there is no function.
First thing to do is to create the function.

```
Function FT(mycell As Range)
FT = mycell.Formula
End Function
```

This gives us the same function as `FORMULATEXT()` but by using `FT()`

How to add a macro or function?
Well you need to go to the VBA window.
You can do this by using the macro button on the view tab, or the Visual Basic button from the developer tab.
Another options is to right click the sheet, and press *view code*.
[image]

Then you add a module by right clicking in the box containing the sheets.
[image]

And then you just have to paste the function in the module:
[image]

**Step 2 - The conditional formatting**
Once we have the function this isn't so hard anymore. 
Too lookup a partial string, to be able to return *=3* out of *=3+10*, we can use the `SEARCH()`Function paired with the `ISNUMBER()` to return a TRUE/FALSE. Exactly what we need for our formatting.
`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("=3",A1))` Would only work if the actual cell value contained `"=3"` but it only contains `13`
Therefore we now use the new function to check against the formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("=3",FT(A1)))
```

**____________________________________**

***By creating the conditional formatting in cell A1, and referring only to A1 as the range in the formula, the autofill function of excel will automatically adjust the formula to fit every cell.***

Here is an example of how I check for cells with formulas containing "=1" and "=3" in Column A to H:

[image][image]

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Christofer,

Thanks for the response on this!  I feel like im getting very close on a resolution, but my struggle with your formula is that I don't know what "A1" indicates.  When I copied and pasted your formula as is, nothing happened.  So I attempted to make some tweaks.  Please let me know if the below formula will/should work (because it isn't)

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("=3",FORMULATEXT(A1)))

I also tried:

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("=3",FORMULATEXT(H1:H5000)))

I was unsure how to make macro you provided so I just used FORMULATEXT and seemed to work in several of my tests, not accurately.

Comment: @Dan Well as I said, the problem with `FORMULATEXT`is that it doesn't exist in excel 2010. I'll try to update with some tips on creating a macro.

Comment: @Dan A1 simply refers to the cell A1. Create the conditional formatting while having the A1 cell selected. Excel will then automatically adjust it, so that on A2 it will refer to A2, B1 to B1 and so on, when you apply it to a greater range.